# Decode JSON using Dart Isolates

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

Does it make sense to do `jsonDecode` with Isolate if the message passing between isolates is encoding into binary data and back again?

Answer (score 1):

If decoding a chunk of JSON requires more than a frame of CPU, you'll get dropped frames, so it's pretty much mandatory at that point. And if you use `Isolate.run`, there's minimal copying between threads, especially on the return value.

Comment: Can you please provide some information about copying objects between isolates?

Comment: Yes, the dart.dev website has entire sections with examples on using async and isolates.

Comment: But there is no information about the serialization and deserialization mechanism that is used to exchange objects between isolates

Comment: That's because Isolate.run uses Sendport/Receiveport, and for isolates in the same isolatepool, it's pretty much everything.  See the SendPort documentation and the Isolate.run docs.